# How to test common error ErrorController in spring-boot with junit

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, junit

In a spring boot project, I'd like to test my ErrorController with Junit.
The code is as the following snippet.

```
@RestController
public class ApiErrorController implements ErrorController {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApiErrorController.class);

  @Value("${server.error.path}")
  private String errorPath;

  @Override
  public String getErrorPath() {
    return this.errorPath;
  }

  @RequestMapping("/error")
  public ResponseEntity<ErrorResult> error(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    String requestURI = (String) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri");
    LOGGER.info("error handling start url = {}", requestURI);

    String servletMessage = (String) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.message");
    Integer servletStatus = (Integer) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");

    String[] messages = new String[0];
    if (!StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(servletMessage)) {
      messages = new String[] { servletMessage };
    }
    HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    try {
      if (servletStatus != null && servletStatus instanceof Integer) {
        status = HttpStatus.valueOf(servletStatus);
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) { // test this exception
      LOGGER.warn("http status not converted.{}", request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code"), ex);
    }
    ErrorResult body = new ErrorResult();
    body.setMessages(messages);
    ResponseEntity<ErrorResult> responseResult = new ResponseEntity<>(body, status);
    return responseResult;
  }
}
```

When a business exception happened in my Controller(for example AbcController), then the program goes into the ExceptionControllerAdvice class.
If an exception happened in ExceptionControllerAdvice, then the program goes into the above ApiErrorController class.

Could someone tell me how to test the case that `HttpStatus.valueOf(servletStatus)` fail?
In addition, I want `request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.message")` return a non-empty string.
How to achieve what I'd like to test?

By the way, I **don't want to only test the logic of `error` method**. I'd like to use `AbcController` I mentioned to make the test. What I want is when a error happens in `AbcController`, then the `error` method in `ApiErrorController` can handle it successfully.

**APPEND**:
For example, `ExceptionControllerAdvice` will handle the business exception.

```
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)
public class ExceptionControllerAdvice {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExceptionControllerAdvice.class);

  @ExceptionHandler({ BusinessCloudException.class })
  public ResponseEntity<ErrorResult> handleBlCloudException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                                            BlCloudException ex) {

    HttpStatus status = ErrorUtils.toHttpStatus(ex.getType());
    ErrorResult body = new ErrorResult();
    body.setMessages(ex.getMessageArray());
    ResponseEntity<ErrorResult> responseResult = new ResponseEntity<>(body, status);
    return responseResult;
  }
}
```

If there's an error happened in the `handleBlCloudException` method, then the program goes into `ApiErrorController` to handle this error.

How do the program produce the a specific `servletStatus` and `javax.servlet.error.message`? How to mock to do this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is quite a lot going on in that error method. You might consider moving some of the logic to a specialized class / public methods.

Apart from that i would suggest using Mockito.

Fist of all create a method to encapsulate the HttpStatus retrieval:

```
HttpStatus getHttpStatusByServletStatus(Integer servletStatus){
    return HttpStatus.valueOf(servletStatus);
}
```

and change your code to :

```
  if (servletStatus != null && servletStatus instanceof Integer) {
    status = getHttpStatusByServletStatus(servletStatus);
  }
```

Then the test class:

public ApiErrorControllerTest{

```
 @Spy
 private ApiErrorController apiErrorController; 

 @Mock
 HttpServletRequest requestMock;
 @Mock
 HttpServletResponse responseMock;

 @Befire
 public void init(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
 }

 @Test
 public void test(){
    // Arrange

   HttpStatus expectedStatus = // expected status
   String expectedErrorMessage = // ..

   doReturn(expectedStatus).when(apiErrorController)
     .getHttpStatusByServletStatus(Mockito.anyString());

   when(requestMock.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.message"))
     .thenReturn(expectedErrorMessage);

   // other setup.. 

   // Act
   apiErrorController.error(requestMock, responseMock);

   // Assertions
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. But I don't want to only test the logic of `error` method. I'd like to use `AbcController` I mentioned to make the test. What I want is when a error happens in `AbcController`, then the `error` method in `ApiErrorController` can handle it successfully.

Comment: So basically you want to write an integration test?

Comment: Yes, you can think so. Maybe it looks like an  integration test.

Comment: Well i cant say anythign without having the impl here.. whats the problem that you cannot repoduce that scenario?